# Submitting select helper values via link_to not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have been converting a verbose Ruby/Sinatra script to Rails and have run into an issue submitting my form's selected values. The path should wind up http://localhost:3000/show?application=app&version=1.0.0.

Here is my code:

```
<form>
    <span title= "Application Name">
        Application:
        <%= collection_select(:DeathBurritoApplication, :death_burrito_name, @applications, :death_burrito_name, :death_burrito_name) %>
    </span>

    <span title="Version">
        Jira Version:
        <%= select("JiraBug", "jira_version_name", @jira_ver_array, :selected => params[:version] ) %>
    </span>

    <span title="Death Burrito Version">
        Death Burrito Version: <%= select("DeathBurritoAppVersion", "death_burrito_version", @db_ver_array ) %>
    </span>

    <span title="Submit"><%= link_to "Submit", :controller => "dashboard", :action => "show", :application => @application, :version => "" %></span>
</form>
```

And here is the generated html:

```
<form>
    <span title= "Application Name">
        Application:
        <select id="DeathBurritoApplication_death_burrito_name" name="DeathBurritoApplication[death_burrito_name]"><option value="LongListOfAppsIRemoved">LongListOfAppsIRemoved</option>
    </span>

    <span title="Version">
        Jira Version:
        <select id="JiraBug_jira_version_name" name="JiraBug[jira_version_name]"><option value="Not assigned">Not assigned</option>
<option value="6.20.1">6.20.1</option>
<option value="6.22">6.22</option>
<option value="6.23">6.23</option>
<option value="6.24">6.24</option>
<option value="Future release">Future release</option>
<option value="6.26">6.26</option></select>
    </span>

    <span title="Death Burrito Version">
        Death Burrito Version: <select id="DeathBurritoAppVersion_death_burrito_version" name="DeathBurritoAppVersion[death_burrito_version]"><option value="Not Found">Not Found</option></select>
    </span>

    <span title="new_submit"><a href="/dashboard/show?application=Applyweb+Web&amp;version=">Submit</a></span>
    <span title="Submit"><input class="graph_button" id="dashboard_submit_button" src="/images/submit.png?1311179528" type="image" /></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few issues with my script that changing to form_tag, select_tag and submit_tag resolved.